# Higher order derivatives with functorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm computing higher order derivatives using nested jacobian from `pytorch`/`functorch`.
$$f(x, y, z, \dots) : R^{m_x} \times R^{m_y} \times R^{m_z} \times \dots \to R^{m} $$
Given a function `f(x, y, z, ...)` and derivative orders for first several arguments `(nx, ny, nz, ..)`, partial derivatives can be computed and used as Taylor series representation of the original function.

I'm aware that nesting jacobian generates redundancy for high orders, e.g. both `dxdyf` and `dydxf` are computed. I'm looking for a style/code review for `derivative` function. In particular, I would like to avoid using nested `kwarg`.

## Code

```py
"""
Derivative module.

"""
from __future__ import annotations

import torch
import functorch

from typing import Iterator
from typing import Callable

from math import factorial
from multimethod import multimethod


def flatten(table:tuple) -> Iterator:
    """
    Flatten a nested tuple.

    Parameters
    ----------
    table: tuple
        input (nested) tuple

    Returns
    -------
    flattened tuple generator (iterator)

    """
    if isinstance(table, tuple): 
        for _ in table: yield from flatten(_) 
    else: 
        yield table
        
        
@multimethod
def derivative(order:int,
               function:Callable,
               *args,
               jacobian:Callable=functorch.jacfwd) -> list:
    """
    Compute input function derivatives with respet to the first argument upto a given order.
    
    Input function is expected to return a tensor or a (nested) list of tensors
    The first function argument is expected to be a tensor
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    order: int
        maximum derivative order
    function: Callable
        input function
    *args:
        input function arguments
    jacobian: Callable, optional, default=functorch.jacfwd
        functorch.jacfwd or functorch.jacrev

    Returns
    -------
    function derivatives (list)

    """
    def local(x, *xs):
        y = function(x, *xs)
        return y, y

    for _ in range(order):
        def local(x, *xs, local=local):
            y, ys = jacobian(local, has_aux=True)(x, *xs)
            return y, (ys, y)

    _, ys = local(*args)

    return list(flatten(ys))


@multimethod
def derivative(order:tuple[int, ...],
               function:Callable,
               *args,
               jacobian:Callable=functorch.jacfwd) -> list:
    """
    Compute input function derivatives with respet to several first function arguments upto corresponding given orders.
    
    Input function is expected to return a tensor or a (nested) list of tensors
    The first several function arguments are expected to be tensors

    Parameters
    ----------
    order: tuple[int, ...]
        maximum derivative orders
    function: Callable
        input function
    *args:
        input function arguments
    jacobian: Callable, optional, default=functorch.jacfwd
        functorch.jacfwd or functorch.jacrev

    Returns
    -------
    function derivatives (list)

    """
    pars = [*args][len(order):]
    
    def fixed(*args):
        return function(*args, *pars)

    def build(order, value):
        def local(*args):
            return derivative(order, lambda x: fixed(*args, x), value, jacobian=jacobian)
        return local
    
    (order, value), *rest = zip(order, args)
    for degree, tensor in reversed(rest):
        def build(order, value, build=build(degree, tensor)):
            def local(*args):
                return derivative(order, lambda x: build(*args, x), value, jacobian=jacobian)
            return local
        
    return build(order, value)()


@multimethod
def evaluate(table:list, 
             point:list[torch.Tensor]) -> torch.Tensor:
    """
    Evaluate input table of derivatives at a given (deviation) point.
        
    Parameters
    ----------
    table: list
        input table of derivatives
    point: list[torch.Tensor]
        evaluation point
        
    Returns
    ----------
    value (torch.Tensor)
        
    """
    return sum(evaluate([i], subtable, point) for i, subtable in enumerate(table))


@multimethod
def evaluate(index:list[int], table:list, point:list[torch.Tensor]) -> torch.Tensor:
    return sum(evaluate(index + [i], subtable, point) for i, subtable in enumerate(table))


@multimethod
def evaluate(index:list[int], table:torch.Tensor, point:list[torch.Tensor]) -> torch.Tensor:
    factor = 1.0
    for position, order in enumerate(index):
        factor *= 1.0/factorial(order)
        value = point[position]
        if value.ndim > 0:
            for _ in range(order): table @= value
        else:
            table *= value**order
    return factor*table
```

## Examples

```py
print(torch.__version__)
print(functorch.__version__)
# 1.13.0+cu117
# 1.13.0+cu117
```

```py
# explicit nested derivatives

# set test function

# f: R x R x R -> R

def f(x, y, z):
    return (1.0 + (2.0 + 3.0*z)*y)*x

# set derivatives order

nx, ny, nz = 1, 1, 1

# set evaluation point

px = torch.tensor(1.0, dtype=torch.float64)
py = torch.tensor(1.0, dtype=torch.float64)
pz = torch.tensor(1.0, dtype=torch.float64)

# compute derivatives (explicit nesting)

t1 = derivative(nx, lambda x: derivative(ny, lambda y: derivative(nz, lambda z: f(x, y, z), pz), py), px)

# compute derivatives (implicit nesting)

t2 = derivative((nx, ny, nz), f, px, py, pz)

# compare derivatives

print(all(k1 == k2 for i1, i2 in zip(t1, t2) for j1, j2 in zip(i1, i1) for k1, k2 in zip(j1, j1)))

# evaluate at a different point

vx = torch.tensor(5.0, dtype=torch.float64)
vy = torch.tensor(5.0, dtype=torch.float64)
vz = torch.tensor(5.0, dtype=torch.float64)

print(f(vx, vy, vz))
print(evaluate(t1, [vx - px, vy - py, vz - pz]))
print(evaluate(t2, [vx - px, vy - py, vz - pz]))

# True
# tensor(4.300000000000e+02, dtype=torch.float64)
# tensor(4.300000000000e+02, dtype=torch.float64)
# tensor(4.300000000000e+02, dtype=torch.float64)
```

````py
# derivatives with respect to several vector arguments

# set test function

# f: R^2 x R^3 x R^4 -> R^2

def f(x, y, z):
    x1, x2 = x
    y1, y2, y3 = y
    z1, z2, z3, z4 = z
    
    Z1 = (1 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4)**2
    Z2 = (1 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4)**2
    Z3 = (1 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4)**2
    Z4 = (1 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4)**2
    
    Y1 = (Z1 + Z2)*(1 + y1 + y2 + y3)**2
    Y2 = (Z2 + Z3)*(1 + y1 + y2 + y3)**2
    Y3 = (Z3 + Z4)*(1 + y1 + y2 + y3)**2
    
    X1 = (Y1 + Y2)*(1 + x1 + x2)**2
    X2 = (Y2 + Y3)*(1 + x1 + x2)**2
    
    return torch.stack([X1, X2])

# set derivatives order

nx, ny, nz = 2, 2, 2

# set evaluation point

px = torch.tensor([0.0, 0.0], dtype = torch.float64)
py = torch.tensor([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype = torch.float64)
pz = torch.tensor([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype = torch.float64)

# compute derivatives

table = derivative((nx, ny, nz), f, px, py, pz)

# evaluate at a different point

vx = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0], dtype = torch.float64)
vy = torch.tensor([3.0, 4.0, 5.0], dtype = torch.float64)
vz = torch.tensor([6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0], dtype = torch.float64)

print(f(vx, vy, vz))
print(evaluate(table, [vx - px, vy - py, vz - pz]))

# tensor([1.039417600000e+07, 1.039417600000e+07], dtype=torch.float64)
# tensor([1.039417600000e+07, 1.039417600000e+07], dtype=torch.float64)

# structure of derivatives

# [
#     [
#         [          f,           dz f,           dzdz f, ...],
#         [       dy f,        dy dz f,        dy dzdz f, ...],
#         [     dydy f,      dydy dz f,      dydy dzdz f, ...],
#         ...
#     ],
#     [
#         [       dx f,        dx dz f,        dx dzdz f, ...],
#         [    dx dy f,     dx dy dz f,     dx dy dzdz f, ...],
#         [  dx dydy f,   dx dydy dz f,   dx dydy dzdz f, ...],
#         ...
#     ],
#     [
#         [     dxdx f,      dxdx dz f,      dxdx dzdz f, ...],
#         [  dxdx dy f,   dxdx dy dz f,   dxdx dy dzdz f, ...],
#         [dxdx dydy f, dxdx dydy dz f, dxdx dydy dzdz f, ...],
#         ...
#     ],
#     ...
# ]

print(table[0][0][0].shape) # f
print(table[1][0][1].shape) # dx dz f
print(table[2][2][2].shape) # dxdx dydy dzdz f

# torch.Size([2])
# torch.Size([2, 4, 2])
# torch.Size([2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2])
```
````